# Error During Docker Build for Node.js App: "npm install" Fails with ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I'm attempting to Dockerize my Node.js application, which also serves an Angular frontend. The application works well locally, but when I try to build the Docker image, the npm install step fails due to a network timeout error. Here's the relevant part of the Docker build output:

```
 [+] Building 578.9s (8/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 663B
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16
 => [internal] load build context
 => => transferring context: 160.92kB
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:16@sha256:f77a1aef2da8d83e45ec990f45df50f1a286c5fe8bbfb8c6e4246c6389705c0b
 => [2/5] WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 => [3/5] COPY package*.json ./
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN npm install
------
 > [4/5] RUN npm install:
# output omitted for brevity
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist/-/yallist-4.0.0.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
# more output omitted
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Node.js image as the parent image
FROM node:16-alpine

# Set the working directory in the Docker container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (or yarn.lock) into the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install any dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the Node.js application into the container
COPY . .

# Make your service's port available to the outside
EXPOSE 8080

# Run your application
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```